# Determining average of one column in relation to another in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table `Messages` which stores system messages sent, with a `DateTime` stamp.

I need to figure out the easiest way to determine how many messages are sent per day on average. I know about the `AVG()` function in SQL Server, but for some reason I just can't get the query written properly, as its failing.

The simplified select statement without the math is:

```
select MessageID, MessageText, DateTimeStamp
from Messages
```

which would bring back a return similar to:

```
1   Hi!                 2016-10-25 21:02:45.130
2   Hi back to you.     2016-10-25 22:02:45.100
3   This is a message.  2016-10-26 14:02:45.130
4   Indeed it is.       2016-10-27 20:01:45.130
5   Final test.         2016-11-10 13:02:45.130
6   Response to test.   2016-11-10 19:00:00.130
```

I just need to provide an average message sent per day. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: Honestly Im just looking for a numeric average. So, in the above example, if 2 messages are sent on 10-25, 1 on 10-26, 1 on 10-27, and 2 on 11-10, then the average message per day would be 1.5 msgs per day. Obviously I may tweak the final query to deal with ranges, but for now, just some help with the syntax for the math would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sum` window function to do this.

```
select 
1.0*sum(count(*)) over()/count(distinct cast(DateTimeStamp as date)) as avg_messages
from Messages
```

or more simply

```
select 1.0*count(*)/count(distinct cast(DateTimeStamp as date))
from Messages
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!